# How to use Semantic UI CDN?

Tags: cdn, semantic-ui

How to include Semantic UI to HTML page using CDN? The CDN link is https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui, but how to use it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated for current version 2.4.2**

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

For checking updated version, see [JSDeliver CDN page](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/semantic-ui).

Comment: thanks, but how does one know which jquery version shall be used with which semantic ui version?

Answer (score 70):

You just need to copy the URL of the files you want to use for Semantic UI, and put it in your header under a script or link tag as the "src" or "href" value.

For Semantic UI, you need three files for general use:

- semantic.min.css
- jquery.min.js (from JQuery CDN)
- semantic.min.js

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Semantic UI CDN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- Your Semantic UI Code -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: You don't necessarily **need** those 3 files for everything. For example, table.min.css works alone if you're just making simple tables.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta Just to clarify, does the `semantic.min.js` and `semantic.min.css` together include *everything*, or do I have to include a corresponding file for each component that I want to use?

Comment: @DavidTan Good question. Apparently `semantic.min.js` and `semantic.min.css` contain everything. If you view the source of their [Table API](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html), you will notice that they're only including `semantic.min.js` and `semantic.min.css` and not `table.min.css` which you can find the contents of inside the `semantic.min.css` file.

Comment: I see, so `table.min.css` and the other individual component files are just stand-alone parts of Semantic-UI for people that don't want to load the entire thing to use a small part of it?

Comment: That is my understanding of it, yes.

Comment: What about applying a theme?

Comment: May I add you a question? In case, I want to use all components of semantic so I need to link to each component or semantic.min.css has included all of them? Please help. And how about using theme?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and tried following the answer from @NitinJadhav , but had trouble getting components/modules like the [Accordion](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html) to actually be interactive. It was styled correctly, but wouldn't open or collapse like expected.

I did include the CDNs, but I *also* had to add some extra JavaScript. I made a JS file, `application.js` and linked to it in my HTML file.

So my `<head>` tag looked like:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha256-9mbkOfVho3ZPXfM7W8sV2SndrGDuh7wuyLjtsWeTI1Q=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js" integrity="sha256-t8GepnyPmw9t+foMh3mKNvcorqNHamSKtKRxxpUEgFI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js" ></script>
</head>
```

`application.js` needs to come last, because I plan to use jQuery and Semantic UI jQuery in the file.

I went back to the documentation for the Accordion and  clicked on the "Usage" tab to grab the required jQuery.

[image: Semantic UI Accordion jQuery]

Then I dumped it in `application.js`, and wrapped it in a `$(document).ready`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
});
```

and that got it to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on [JSDeliver](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/semantic-ui?path=dist) under dist folder.